# How can I pass functions as params to an AngularJS Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can pass strings and objects, but for some reason when I add callback functions to my scope object that I'm using as configurable options, Angular strips them out.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    scope.options = {{ options }}
    <br><br>
    <div my-directive="{{ options }}"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('demo2', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        test_str: 'test',
        init_cb: function() {
            alert('custom init callback');
        },
        apply_cb: function() {
            alert('custom apply callback');
        }
    };
});
app.directive('myDirective', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var options = attrs.myDirective;
        scope.init(options);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        link: link,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.defaults = {
                init_cb: function() {
                    alert('default init callback');
                },
                apply_cb: function() {
                    alert('default apply callback');
                }
            };
            $scope.settings = {};

            $scope.init = function(options) {
                $scope.settings = $.extend({}, $scope.defaults, $scope.options);

                // init cb.
                $scope.settings.init_cb();

                // apply cb.
                $scope.settings.apply_cb();
            };
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/revolunet/pHZNY/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As an update, I've found that if I `console.log($scope.options)` in `DemoCtrl` the obj contains the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the attr, which can only be a string, when you need to just pass the actual variable into the scope:

```
var app = angular.module('demo2', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        test_str: 'test',
        init_cb: function() {
            alert('custom init callback');
        },
        apply_cb: function() {
            alert('custom apply callback');
        }
    };
});
app.directive('myDirective', ['$parse', function($parse) {


    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { //use scope to pass in variables
            options: '=myDirective'
        },

        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {


            $scope.defaults = {
                init_cb: function() {
                    alert('default init callback');
                },
                apply_cb: function() {
                    alert('default apply callback');
                }
            };
            $scope.settings = {};

            $scope.init = function(options) {
                $scope.settings = angular.extend({}, $scope.defaults, $scope.options);

                // init cb.
                $scope.settings.init_cb();

                // apply cb.
                $scope.settings.apply_cb();
            }();
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner, but I still have issues adding methods to an object in the scope of `DemoCtrl`. Add `console.log($scope.options)` to `DemoCtrl` and it shows the methods. But if you print the expression to the page `{{ $scope.options }}` in the HTML it prints the object without the methods. For some reason Angular seems to strip them out...

Comment: For it to render, it is converting the object to a JSON string, and JSON doesn't contain functions.  If you just need to be able to modify the original options, set scope to false. see http://jsfiddle.net/pHZNY/8/

Comment: I am trying to create an easy way to extend the default options with custom callback functions, similar to the way a jQuery plugin does. If I insert an object into the directive, it works. If I use a $scope model and use an expression to associate the value to the directive in the HTML, it doesn't work. I don't know why Angular strips the functions from the $scope model.

Comment: I didn't realize I had access to `$scope.$parent.options` within the directive's controller. I'm still writing AngularJS with a jQuery mentality. That being said, understanding the scope operators `'='`, `'@'`, and `'&'` has helped immensely. Thank you for pointing me onto them!

Comment: For anyone else who may be looking at this. I discovered that AngularJS strips functions from $scope models in the interpolation process. So anytime you use `{{ expression }}` if your expression model contains a function (`$scope.expression = { callback: function() { //cb code... } }`) it will be converted to a JSON str as @dave said above.